# Как добавить свойство структуры в отдельный массив и отсортировать его?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Мне необходимо отсортировать объекты (музыкальные альбомы) по названию от А до Я.

Есть массив, в котором хранятся все альбомы

```
var albums: [Album] = [
        Album(name: "Fly me to the Moon", price: 20, artist: "Questa noche", image: "Fly", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Warner", description: ""),
        Album(name: "Violin Classics No. 1", price: 25, artist: "Antonio", image: "Violin", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Worker", description: ""),
        Album(name: "Q42 - Piano intense", price: 25, artist: "Questa noche", image: "Q42", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Barron", description: ""),
        Album(name: "Storms in the middle of", price: 20, artist: "Andrea Casco", image: "Storm", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Naggoli", description: ""),
        Album(name: "Violin Classics No. 1", price: 20, artist: "Antonio", image: "Violin2", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Whicher", description: ""),
        Album(name: "Los Pamperos muchachos", price: 19, artist: "Questa noche", image: "Los", releaseDate: 2017, label: "Warner", description: "")
    ]
```

Мне нужно отсортировать их по названию (свойство - name), и вывести результат при нажатии на кнопку, показываю альбомы с Collection View, архитектура MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел простой ответ,

```
 func sortByNameFromAtoZ() {
    albums.sort(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
}
```

и во вью надо сделать

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```